# Float with no more than 3 decimals

Tags: python-3.x

How to print the calculation of float with only 3 more decimal
If I calculated something and the answer of that calculation is like, 3.33333333...
I just want to print it like 3.333 and that's it

Answer (score 2):

With the round function:

```
round(3.33333333, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use format specifiar

```
num = 3.3333333
print("%.3f"%num)
```

Output:`3.333`

Answer (score 0):

```
a=1.233455543323
print('{0:.3f}'.format(a))
```

output=1.233

Answer (score 0):

you can use `round` function 
syntax: 
`round(number, digits)` 
`number`: Required. The number to be rounded 
`digits`: Optional. The number of decimals to use when rounding the number. Default is 0

```py
num = 3.33333333
print(round(num, 3))
```